# Generate PDF report from Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, reporting, .net-assembly

I have a report "MyCustomReport.rdlc" implemented in an ASPX project.

Now I created an Assembly from which I want to fill this report as well (in a seperate C# file)  in order to later attach it to an email and send it to the costumer, it will also be saved in a local folder.

The datasets on the report remain unchanged.

So basically I need to access my report from the assembly and so generate my PDF from the report template but I cannot use an instance of "LocalReport" in an Assembly project.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can't - simple answer.

If you can't add reference to Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms:

You must change "Target Framework" in your Assembly from ".NET Framework 3.5(4 or 4.5) Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 3.5(4 or 4.5)". So now you can add reference to Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms. Now you can use Render method.

Comment: If you need example with Render fill free to ask me.

Comment: this still requires me to run the assembly from the aspx right? because this should assembly is going to be used with a timer and gets called every night at say 3 am.

Comment: To Render a report. You need two things: 1. MyCustomReport.rdlc - the report file. 2. Datasource for that report file. So if you can get them you can render report. You don't need access to entire ASP project. Just Data Access Layer(DAL) and report file.